# Use of in which ( grammar)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is using in which in the following sentence correct?

“ Although instances occur in which partners start their relationship by telling everything about themselves to each other, such instances are rare”

”In which” can change “where” ! However , I think location of occur is weird

Sentence I write below is right ??

“Although instances in which partners start their relationship by telling everything about themselves to each other occur , such instances are rare“

Answer (score 0):

The use of "in which" is correct, but either "where" or "when" could be used instead.

The phrase "telling everything about themselves to each other" is grammatical, but this might be clearer: "telling each other everything about themselves".

Your changed version, where you move "occur" very far from its subject "instances", is harder to understand than the original.

The phrasing "Although instances occur in which" is grammatical, it might be more readable as "Although there are instances in which..." . Then you don't have to deal with where to put "occur".